# Automatically create CustomTkinter entry boxes and use data entered into them

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I am new to CustomTkinter and GUI so please bear with me.

So in this app I am creating, I want to make a button to add Entry boxes and labels.

First I tried the following code:

```
count = 0
def add_location(): #This function is invoked with a button press
     global wp
     global count
     count += 1
     wp_label = ctk.CTkLabel(master=app, text = "Waypoint " + str(count))
     wp_label.grid(row=1+count,column=0,padx=20,pady=20)
    
     wp = ctk.CTkEntry(master=app, placeholder_text= "Waypoint " + str(count))
     wp.grid(row=1+count, column=1, padx=20, pady=20)
```

This code works fine, when I press the button it puts new Labels and Entry boxes on the screen. But I want to actually use the values entered to these entry boxes, so I decided to make a for loop instead.

```
entry_list = []

def add_location(): #This function is invoked with a button press
    wpn = num.get() #This gets the number of new input boxes needed.
    print(wpn)
    print(entry_list)
    try:
        for count in range(int(wpn)):
            wp_label = ctk.CTkLabel(master=app, text = "Waypoint " + str(count+1))
            wp_label.grid(row=3+count,column=0,padx=20,pady=20)
        
            wp = ctk.CTkEntry(master=app, placeholder_text= "Waypoint " + str(count+1))
            wp.grid(row=3+count, column=1, padx=20, pady=20)
            entry_list.append(wp.get())
            
    except ValueError:
        return
```

So in this one there is an input box to specify the number of New Entry boxes needed. And again this code works fine, it puts the entry boxes on the screen. But I need a method to read data from each of these entry boxes and store them in variables or in a dictionary.

I just want a method to:

A. spawn new entry boxes on the screen with a click of a button
B. Store data entered to all entry boxes for later use.

Also guys, if there is no way to do this using TK, should I just scratch this and make an HTML form linked to a Python file instead? It isn't required to have a Python GUI. Any GUI will work

Thanks

Comment: Just use `entry_list` to store those entry widgets instead of the contents (actually empty strings) from those entry widgets.

Comment: @Okitha Vithanage. What's Python version are you using? I used Python 3.12.1. But never used `try/except` block. Here is image. https://postimg.cc/fJKyWb8X

Comment: @toyotaSupra, I believe I have the same version. The try except is in any case someone enters a string into the no. of waypoints. Which will cause an error because it needs to be an INT

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is use Tkinter variables and append them to the entries.
So tkinter.StringVar will store your entry values and you can use them later.

In this example I created the labels and entries based of a list containing the label names and tkinter.StringVar

Later I create labels, again based on the same list, that show the values of the variables.

```
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter as ctk


def add_entry_line(parent, label_text, variable):
    frame = ctk.CTkFrame(parent)
    frame.pack(pady=(0, 10))

    ctk.CTkLabel(frame, text=label_text).pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=(0, 10))
    ctk.CTkEntry(frame, textvariable=variable).pack(side=tk.LEFT)


root = ctk.CTk()
root.title("Entry Boxes")
root.geometry("400x750")

entries = [[f'Label {index}', tk.StringVar(root)] for index in range(10)]

entry_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(root)
entry_frame.pack(pady=20)

for entry in entries:
    add_entry_line(entry_frame, entry[0], entry[1])

label_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(root)
label_frame.pack()

for entry in entries:
    ctk.CTkLabel(label_frame, textvariable=entry[1], width=200).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Note: If you want to read or write the tkinter.StringVar you have to use get() and .set()

```
var1 = tk.StringVar(root)
var2 = var1.get()
var1.set('new string')
```

Comment: That is what the OP want to use `customtkinter` instead `Tk()`.

Comment: You are right, I updated my answer for customtkinter

Comment: Also use this `var1 = tkinter.StringVar(value="CTkLabel")` insteaf of `var1 = tk.StringVar(root)`

Comment: Maybe not "instead" but I understand assigning root to master is redundant as it is the default. I assume you want to show how to assign a default value while creating the StringVar object?

Comment: @Ovski thanks for the answer. I didn't know about the get() and set(). I will try using this and get back to you